# Help With Bending Surfaces

Tags: edit-mode

I am trying to create a plane so it switches from 0 degrees to 90 degrees in a smooth motion. I've seen it done, and want to try and duplicate it. However. I don't know how. This is as far as I've gotten:

[image]

Right now I am trying to take that center row and bring it out so the angle isn't 90 degrees, but instead is a smoother transition. I have tried to bevel and extrude the edge / vertices but haven't had the results that I am looking for. Thanks in advance.

Comment: you mean you want to round the edge? so why are you not satisfied with bevel?

Comment: When I say round, I want the lower surface curve towards the surface on the side. When I try and use the bevel tool, the image distorts or there are more vertices but no change to the image's appearance.

Comment: do you have a picture of what you want to achieve?

Comment: I managed to solve the problem after starting a new project. For some reason, the edge didn't act up strangely. The bevel works now, but for some mysterious reason the object's traits were changed. and I don't know what I did to cause that problem.

Comment: sorry for wasting your time.

Comment: Maybe, Although I don't know how as I am still relatively new to Blender

Comment: you should show the result so that we understand better what you wanted to achieve

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.